How to migrate application pinned cert to Unpinned cert in Scope VCclient
As security request, we need to migrate application pinned cert to Unpinned cert.
unpinned cert sample code is below
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Certificates\Certificate.pfx", Password);

            if (s_app == null)
            {
                     s_app  = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("<applicationid>")                                                     
                                                      .WithCertificate(certificate, sendX5C: true) // for SNI
                                                      .BuildConcrete();
            }       

But VcClient.VC.SetupAadCredentials(cosmosVC, VcClient.VC.NoProxy, cred) just support Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClientCredentials type.
We need to submit Scope to get the data from cosmos by pipeline, Please overwrite the function SetupAadCredentials to support sendX5C. if not, Could you give us the workaround?
Thanks
